# symfony2 entityMetadata->getFieldNames() not including relational fields

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I try to use $this->entityMetadata->getFieldNames() in Symfony2 to get all the fieldNames from a entity. The array I get in return does not include oneToMany relational fields or any other relational fields for that matter.

Is there a way to get all the fields by using that function? I could of course modify the original code but I wonder why the function does not include all the fields.

The bundle I am having problems with is Ddeboers otherwise excellent [Data Import Bundle](https://github.com/ddeboer/DdeboerDataImportBundle)

Answer (score 1):

The metadata class also includes a function called "getAssociationNames()" which returns the list of relational fields. Please take a look at

http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.2/source-class-Doctrine.ORM.Mapping.ClassMetadataInfo.html

to get an idea of the structure of the information returned by this call